What is the correct way to calculate testnet BTC fees?
Recently, the fees on Testnet seem to be going wild. I tried to send 20,000 satoshi and it cost me 27,000 satoshi. I used a feerate based on blockstream.info's fee estimate and calculated the fee using tx.virtualSize() * estimatefee.
What is the correct way to calculate testnet btc fees?

I'm voting to close this as there doesn't seem to be a question to answer.

sorry for that, i edit it and put my question
